# Autostart script in init.d Raspberry not starting

Tags: service, raspberry-pi, autostart, init.d

I am running a Raspberry Pi with Wheezy and I am trying to start several scripts after booting but for some reason they are not starting and there is also no information / errors in the syslog / messages file.

The header of one of the scripts (all headers are a like and run fine if I start/stop it with the "service xxx start" command)

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myservice
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5 
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Put a short description of the service here
# Description:       Put a long description of the service here
### END INIT INFO
```

When I run the update-rc.d command, this is the only output it gives:

> update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing

Looking in the /etc/rcX.d directors, all scripts are there, starting with S03xxx

I have no idea why the system is not auto starting them. 
(Also check the run level, which is 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing to this

## Default-Start: S 2 3 4 5

Then run your update (you may not need to update, but it won't hurt).

S is for boot only then it will run the next level scripts.

Comment: This produces the following when running update-rc.d:


update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: warning: default start runlevel arguments (2 3 4 5) do not match xxx Default-Start values (S 2 3 4 5)
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (2 3 4 5) of script `xxxx' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5 S).